# Rename [borderlands-pre-sequel] to [borderlands-the-pre-sequel]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

I would like to propose renaming the tag for *Borderlands: The Pre-Sequel* from [borderlands-pre-sequel](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands-pre-sequel) to [borderlands-the-pre-sequel](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands-the-pre-sequel). Presumably the original tag was created before the character limit was raised from 25 to 35.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Renamed the tag to [borderlands-the-pre-sequel](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands-the-pre-sequel) and made the original a synonym.